# How to access database in an HTML5/JS app online and offline with one code base?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, sqlite, cordova

I'm working on an HTML/JavaScript GUI application that will run on mobile devices (using Cordova) and also as a hosted web page that's accessible from a desktop web browser.  I want to give the option to read and store data in a local offline database (SQL database most likely), as well as the option to connect to a web server and read/update data from the server as well.

If anyone has done something similar without having to write the data access routines twice (once for the server side, and once for the client offline storage side), I'd like to get some suggestions.

One solution I am thinking about (which has some unresolved issues still):
I could write the server in any platform (PHP, Java, Js, etc.), but don't want to replicate the data access code for the offline version, so am thinking to do the data access portion in JavaScript--maybe write a node.js server, and use sqlite for local/offline databases (which Cordova supports).  I can't figure out how to provide similar local data functionality on a web browser.

The simplest option would be to run a server on the local machine, but I don't think that is easy in Cordova or on a desktop browser.

Comment: http://hood.ie/ may be a solution. It is a javascript layer which can store data in the browser store an sync to a server, if online.

Comment: hood.ie also led to this site that has a list of similar libraries and solutions, some open source, some commercial services.  http://nobackend.org/solutions.html

Comment: So you are looking for "good old SQL" Services?

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach I'm not sure what that means, can you elaborate?

Comment: I just wanted to know, if you want to use a SQL server like oracle, mssql or mysql instead of key-value or no sql databases.

Comment: The project is small enough that it doesn't matter, but if I can also get access to those products with one code base, that would give me more expansion options.  SQL/relational is easier and more familiar.  Why, do you have suggestions for relational databases too?

Answer (score 4):

Check out PouchDB.  PouchDB is compatible with CouchDB and is 100% Javascript.  You can do some cool offline syncing to online syncing with CouchDB.

Check out https://cloudant.com/blog/pouchdb/ and http://pouchdb.com/faq.html.

Comment: It also has the same API for Node.js, browser storage, and a remote CouchDB. So you really can reuse the same codebase across all three. :)

Comment: PouchDB seems like a nice solution that may do what I need.  It is a NoSql database, so I would not get some of the SQL queries for free.  Several "nobackend.org" solutions use it as well (I'm looking into them as well to see if they do some things I didn't think of asking for!)